# How can I expand a list of letters/numbers in ash?

Tags: busybox, brace-expansion, ash

In busybox, the default shell is ash, so some familiar tricks in bash are not available.  One thing I would like to do is expand a list of letters, like `{a..z}`, which would expand to `a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z` in bash.  Is there another way to do this ash?

Comment: `ash` does not support brace expansion. What would you want to use this list of letters for? There might be a better way of doing it.

Comment: I was walking through a list of drives, so /dev/sd* worked.  However, I realized there doesn't seem to be any list expansion for letters or numbers built in, but maybe there's a better way?  Could just use seq for numbers, but is there something for letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIXly (and with busybox) and on ASCII-based systems (I don't think busybox has ever been found on EBCDIC systems):

```
letters() { awk 'BEGIN{for(i=97;i<123;i++)printf "%c\n", i}'; }
```

Would expand to that list of letters, one per line, so assuming you've not modified `$IFS`,

```
cmd $(letters)
```

would be a way to pass that list as separate arguments to `cmd`. As you'd do with `ksh93`/`zsh`/`bash`'s `cmd {a..z}`.

That's hardly an improvement over

```
letters() { printf '%s\n' a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z; }
```

though. To be able to do the equivalent of `foo{a..z}bar`, you could define a:

```
letters() { printf "${1-%s\n}" a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z; }
```

instead and call it as:

```
cmd $(letters 'foo%sbar\n')
```

You can expand on that kind of approach, by doing something like:

```
format() { awk -v format="$1" '{printf format, $0}' ;}
```

And then do:

```
$ seq 97 100 | format 'foo%cbar\n'
fooabar
foobbar
foocbar
foodbar
```

```
$ seq 4 | format '%04d\n'
0001
0002
0003
0004
```

(though the latter can also be written `seq -w 0004`)

`seq` is not a POSIX command, but `busybox` does come with it.

Note that busybox `sh` is based on `ash` by default but can alternatively be configured at build time to use a `hush`-based shell which does support brace expansion. But that's only the csh-style `{a,b}`, not zsh-style `{1..10}`, `{a..z}` or the more advanced forms found in ksh93/zsh/bash.

Answer (score 2):

The `ash` shell does not support brace expansions.

Using Perl, you could do

```
perl -e 'print join("\n",a..z), "\n"'
```

where the first `\n` (in `join()`) could be replaced by the delimiter of your choice.

If you have the `jot` utility available,

```
jot -c - a z
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Busybox install comes with the `hush` shell, you can use that instead. It supports brace expansions.

Comment: busybox hush supporting brace expansion (though not the `{1..4}`, `{a..f}` forms) was already mentioned in the accepted answer.